# Realm; making an optional attribute required in future migration

Tags: swift, realm

I have a Realm model which has an optional `NSDate` property `expiryDate`, which stores the date that the object will no longer be usable after.

This property needs to be changed such that the `expiryDate` is required. Because there are multiple versions of our app out there, I want to avoid having a function in our data layer which checks to see if the `expiryDate` property on each one of the objects is set, and if not, sets it to a default value.

I plan on updating our schema to replace

```
dynamic var expiryDate: NSDate?
```

with

```
dynamic var expiryDate: NSDate = NSDate().dateByAddingSeconds(SomeMaxExpiryDateInSeconds)
```

Will this change mean that all previously stored objects with an `expiryDate` that is not set, will be set to `NSDate().dateByAddingSeconds(SomeMaxExpiryDateInSeconds)` and will be saved accordingly to Realm? Or will this property be recalculated every time that it is accessed?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to change value types during a Realm migration, including between making a given property optional or non-optional. During the migration, you would have to go through and assign a value to each `expiryDate` object that was previously `nil`.

```
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
    schemaVersion: 1,
    migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
            migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Object.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                if oldObject["expiryDate"] == nil {
                    newObject["expiryDate"] = Date().dateByAddingSeconds(SomeMaxExpiryDateInSeconds)
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: That's a good solution, and one I have already thought about. As mentioned in the question, I don't want to use a method like this as it adds code-smell to the code-base as well as redundant code. It's more or less the same as having `if iOS 9` littered everywhere. The same question applies, can I update the dynamic var with a default value to solve the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, if you want to convert a Realm property from optional to non-optional, it's necessary to perform a migration. Sorry that you think it looks like code-smell. We usually put our Realm `Configurations` in a Constants file so they're not directly in the code-base to try and avoid that. If you can tolerate `expiryDate` remaining as an optional, you can certainly change its default value for any new objects created after this fact, but you'll still need a solution for any older objects that are still `nil`.

Comment: Instead of a migration, you could just do a query for all objects with a `nil` expiry date object and update them as a one-off.